# Testcafe is throwing this._connectionsReadyTimeout.unref is not a function exception. Browser opens and test never runs

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to run a testCafe test using test cafe API:-

```
await testCafe.createRunner().src(./testFile.ts).browsers("Chrome").run();
```

Every time I try to run the test, testCafe API throws this error with the following stacktrace:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this._connectionsReadyTimeout.unref is not a function
    at BrowserSet.dispose (C:\Users\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:161:43)
    at C:\Users\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:129:34
    at Bootstrapper._getBrowserConnections (C:\Users\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:214:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Bootstrapper._bootstrapParallel (C:\Users\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:375:38)
    at Bootstrapper.createRunnableConfiguration (C:\Users\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:411:42)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you please specify your TestCafe and OS version and share the code of your test and runner? I cannot reproduce the same issue using only the posted expression. Please note that the test file name in `src` must be a string and needs to be enclosed in singular or double quotes. The browser name is case-sensitive, and the correct case is `chrome`.

Comment: @AndreyBelym I am using testcafe - 1.9.0, Chrome:  86.0, Node: 14.11.0, and Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1909. I did debug the code and found out that this issue was being generated due to a timeoutError - "Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. (E1004). The test code looks as follows: import { Selector } from 'testcafe'; fixture 'New Project'.page("google.com/"); test ('New test case', async t => { }); Along with this issue, could you please tell me if there is any way to run the test as a string instead of running it using the test file?

Comment: When the timeout to establish a connection for a browser passed, we throw an error about it and try to dispose of the used Node.js timer using its [unref](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref) method. But in your case, this method appears to be not a function. We are still not able to reproduce it, so I suggest you update TestCafe to the latest version. If the error persists, please [create](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) a bug report in the TestCafe repo with more details: full code of your runner and the way you execute it.

Comment: Regarding the question about passing test code as a string - there is no such feature yet, but you can create a file with test code using Node.js [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) package and specify its name in the [src](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/testcafe-api/runner/src.html) method of the TestCafe runner.

Comment: @wentwrong Thank you so much for your response! The issue is resolved now.

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem is resolved. Could you please clarify if updating to the latest TestCafe version solved it? I think this can be helpful to those who may encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: @wentwrong the issue was not at all with testcafe but with electron renderer process calling the main process at my end.